# Error While executing a SSIS package which contains a script task through SQL Server SSISDB

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS project that contains foreach loop containers that get the files from a source folder, do the ETL, and then using Script Task i zip each file and then move it to an archive folder.
 The process runs with no issues when i execute it from visual studio. However, when i deploy it to SSISDB i get this error message:

> "Script Task: error exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation".

When I go back to visual studio and disable the script tasks and deploy it again to SSISDB, it runs without any errors in SSISDB.

Could it be that the SQL login doesn't have the permission to move and modify files? If so, how to solve this?

Your help is so much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this definitely sounds like a file folder permission issue.  When you execute in Visual Studio, you are using your user account.  When you execute on the server you are probably using a service account.  That account will need security permissions against the folders where it is doing file operations.

Comment: @TroyWitthoeft Thanks for the reply. I tried to give the SQL login the needed permissions but that didn't solve the issue. 

As a temporarily solution, i replaced the Script Task that zip and moves the files with File System Task that moves the files to a temp folder, and later i trigger a batch file to zip them and move them. 

I'd appreciate if you could suggest a way to give the SQL login the permissions needed to solve that.